# Google Home: Send email when an intent is invoke

Tags: node.js, webhooks, actions-on-google, google-home

I want to send email through the Google Home when a user invokes a specific intent (using fulfillment).

Please tell me how we can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

First a clarification - your fulfillment code doesn't run on the Google Home device itself. It runs on a cloud service that you control. Since it is invoked via a web call, we sometimes call this a "webhook".

Exactly how you do this, however, will depend on your specific requirements and the specific platform you are running on. For example - do you want the email to come from the user or have the Reply-to address for the user? Do you want to get the email so you know someone has triggered the Intent so they're sending you info? What server are you running your webhook on - one that you control directly (possibly on AWS or the Google Cloud Platform) or a "serverless" resource such as AWS Lambda or Firebase Cloud Functions or something different? These are things we can't answer for you.

You will need to know how to send email for your scenario on your platform - ignoring the Actions on Google component for now. Once you know how to do that, you can integrate it with your Action.

If you're having problems, post a question with as much information as possible about what you've tried and what isn't working - including error messages or logs if possible.